# Восстановление interval-а по нажатию на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "Return Interval" процедура продолжала действие. Что в коде неправильно?

```js
let colors = ["green", "red", "blue", "black"];
let div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
let x = -1;
let y = 2000;

let changeColors = setInterval(function() {
    x += 1;
    div[0].style.backgroundColor = colors[x];
    if (x === colors.length) {
        x = -1;
    }
}, 2000)

buttons[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
    clearInterval(changeColors);
    changeColors = null;
})

buttons[1].addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (changeColors === null) {
        let changeColors = setInterval(function() {
            x += 1;
            div[0].style.gackgroundColor = colors[x];
            if (x === colors.length) {
                x = -1;
            }
            buttons[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
                clearInterval(changeColors) 
            });
        }, 2000)
    };
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<button>Clear Interval</button>
<button>Return Interval</button>
```

Comment: Добавлять всё новые и новые обработчики события на каждой итерации интервала - это очень плохая идея. Тем более что у вас и так есть нужный обработчик, заранее заданный вне цикла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const colors = ["green", "red", "blue", "black"];
const div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
let x = 0;
const changeColor = () => {
  div[0].style.backgroundColor = colors[x++];
  if(x === colors.length){
    x = 0;
  }
}

let changeColors = setInterval(changeColor, 1000);

buttons[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
  clearInterval(changeColors);
  changeColors = null;
})

buttons[1].addEventListener('click', function(){
  if(changeColors === null){
    changeColors = setInterval(changeColor, 1000);
  };
})
```

```css
div{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<button>Clear Interval</button>
<button>Return Interval</button>
```